# Sorting nulls and numbers to mimic tabindex HTML attribute functionality

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, sorting, tabindex

I have a pretty weird problem with sorting in JavaScript. I've wandered into this wonderfully and horribly confusing world of sorting, and was wondering if you guys could help me out:

Basically, I'm trying to mimic the tabindex HTML attribute, which basically changes the order of 'tabbing' through the page: Elements with a tabindex are first, with the smallest positive number first, going down, and the elements without tabindex are last in an unchanged order. So, it's like this:

> tabindex=1, tabindex=2, tabindex=5, tabindex=5000, no tabindex, no tabindex, no tabindex, etc...

I'm trying to get this working. In Chrome it doesn't work because of (I think, at least) the sorting algorithm it uses compared to all other major browsers.

What's returned in Chrome is sporadic and weird, with one element completely out of order and other elements that used to be at the top instead at the bottom.

In all other browsers, it works (except the tabindex'd elements are in a reversed order, but that's really easy to fix, that I was planning on doing after I got this working). This is using the following code:

```
selectElements.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.getAttribute('tabindex')-a.getAttribute('tabindex');
});
```

I believe the problem may stem from the fact that elements without getAttribute are returned null, but what do I know... :P

Let me know what you guys would do to make this work... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving on the answer from @3dgoo, the sort method should check for equality first:

```
selectElements.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.getAttribute('tabindex');
    b = b.getAttribute('tabindex');

    if (a === b) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a === null) {
        return -1;
    } else if (b === null) {
        return 1;
    }

    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Sorry I haven't replied earlier -- I found another method that's kind of roundabout, but I'll try implementing this later. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your sort function is the wrong way around and will return the largest tabindex first. To return a sort on ascending tabindex order you want this:

```
selectElements.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.getAttribute('tabindex') - b.getAttribute('tabindex');
});
```

Note the *a* and *b* variables are switched around.

This does not take into account elements that have a null tabindex attribute, so you want to make some special rules for these cases in your sort algorithm:

```
selectElements.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.getAttribute('tabindex') === b.getAttribute('tabindex')) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (b.getAttribute('tabindex') === null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.getAttribute('tabindex') === null) {
        return 1;
    }
    return a.getAttribute('tabindex') - b.getAttribute('tabindex');
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle which tests this all out. Have a play around if you like: 
http://jsfiddle.net/snyL8/1/

From what I found, there were no differences between Chrome or Firefox with my, or your code.

Comment: The sort method should still really return -1, 0, or 1. What if both values are null?